# how to see what package has been removed after rollback on nixos

Tags: nix, nixos

**introduction**

I wanted to test if

```
nix-env --rollback
```

could change what I changed in  /etc/nixos/configuration.nix
The answer is no but now a package has been delete and I what to know which package has been deleted.

Is there a way to know that?

I know that I could have done

```
nix-env -q
```

before and after the roolback and compare. But if I forget to do that before, I need a solution.

**update**

```
  nix-env -iA nixos.nix-diff

  nix-diff /nix/var/nix/profiles/system /nix/var/nix/profiles/system-$22-link
```

> - /nix/var/nix/profiles/system:{out}

- /nix/var/nix/profiles/system-2-link:{out}
  nix-diff: unknown-deriver: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)"

Comment: It's a bit low level, but you could try `nix-diff /nix/var/nix/profiles/system /nix/var/nix/profiles/system-$N-link` where `$N` is the generation you're reverting to.

Comment: @robertHensing I've updated the question. You can see the problem that I have now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nix profile history` to inspect the package changes.

Suppose you are in version 30, and by install `nix-diff` package you profile becomes version 31, then `nix profile history` will give

```
Version 31 (2022-12-10) <- 30:
  nix-diff: ∅ -> 1.0.18
```

This history preserves even if you rollback from version 31 to 30.

You may also interested in `nix profile diff-closure`, which show diff of the whole closure between profile versions.